# Write Unit test to assert flink function instance is Serializable

Tags: unit-testing, apache-flink, serializable

I had this exception at runtime:

```
org.apache.flink.api.common.InvalidProgramException: The implementation of the RichFlatMapFunction is not serializable. The object probably contains or references non serializable fields.
```

While I understand what's going on and know how to fix it, I'd like to make sure that it doesn't happen again. When someone add non serializable fields to this RichFlatMapFunction class, I'd like a unit test to fail rather than having a failure at runtime.

Is there a way to write a unit test that would assert that the function is serializable, using the same function serialization code as flink?

Answer (score 1):

For this scenario, use **Integration Test** instead.

In the following code, the line `env.execute();` will run the pipeline and serialize the operators `MultiplyByTwo` and `CollectSink`.

You can use it the same way to test if `RichFlatMapFunction` is serializable.

```java
public class ExampleIntegrationTest extends AbstractTestBase {

    @Test
    public void testMultiply() throws Exception {
        StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

        // configure your test environment
        env.setParallelism(1);

        // values are collected in a static variable
        CollectSink.values.clear();

        // create a stream of custom elements and apply transformations
        env.fromElements(1L, 21L, 22L)
                .map(new MultiplyByTwo())
                .addSink(new CollectSink());

        // execute
        env.execute();

        // verify your results
        assertEquals(Lists.newArrayList(2L, 42L, 44L), CollectSink.values);
    }

    // create a testing sink
    private static class CollectSink implements SinkFunction<Long> {

        // must be static
        public static final List<Long> values = new ArrayList<>();

        @Override
        public synchronized void invoke(Long value) throws Exception {
            values.add(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Reference: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/testing.html#integration-testing